# How do i move a letters from exchange to sharepoint library with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, integration, exchange-server

It is necessary to move all letters from a specific sender from Exchange server to the SharePoint library. Is this possible ???
I suppose that this will be a Windows service, which, by timer or time (at night), will move the letters to SharePoint.
On working with Exchange, I found the Management API EWS, but did not find the joint integration of the EWS M API with SharePoint.

I hope for help links or tips!

Comment: I'm afraid you can't implement such a feature with EWS.

Comment: @simon-li Why do you say that??? i can to login in Exchange WebService with Management API EWS and i can to find necessary order by sender